# prices by checkboxes

Tags: php

I want people to see what price they have to pay for a certain product they can buy.

As you can see from the example below if I check on one or more checkboxes there is a certain amount of "discount".

I don't want them to have discount when they just check 1 checkbox, and more discount when they check 3 checkboxes.

What code do I need to put in to make that work! Please help! (the percent discount, 'procent', is 0.9)

```
 <?php 
if ($_POST['sub']){

    $checkv = $_POST['checkv'];
    $checkb = $_POST['checkb'];
    $checke = $_POST['checke'];
    $procent = $_POST['procent'];


    $total = $checkv + $checkb + $checke;
    $total = $total * $procent;
    echo "&#8364; $total,-";

}
?>
```

This is the url: http://sofan.site40.net/Sofan/Untitled-2.php maybe it will help you guys a bit!

Comment: By 'procent' do you mean **Percent (%)**?

Comment: @F4r-20 yup its Swedish word

Comment: By procent i mean as you can see in my form i used a hidden field:

Comment: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="own_huisstijlen.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkv" id="logo" value="150"/>
  <label for="logo"></label> 
  Visitekaartje<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkb" id="huisstijl" value="150"/>
  <label for="huisstijl"></label> 
  Briefpapier<br />
  <input name="checke" type="checkbox" class="Button3" id="flyer" value="175"/>
  <label for="flyer"></label>
  Envelop
  <br /><input name="procent" type="hidden" value="0.9" />
  <input  name="sub" type="submit" class="Button" value="Bereken" />
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken you want the script to ignore `$checkb` and `$checke` if `$checkv` is checked, and ignore `$checke` if `$checkv` or `$checke` is checked.

Replace

```
$checkv = $_POST['checkv'];
$checkb = $_POST['checkb'];
$checke = $_POST['checke'];
```

With

```
$checkv = $_POST['checkv'];
$checkb = $checkv == 0 ? $_POST['checkb'] : 0; // If $checkv doesn't = 0, this = 0
$checke = $checkb == 0 ? $_POST['checke'] : 0; // If $checkb doesn't = 0, this = 0
```

Although this goes in an order, so if both `$checkv` and `$checke` are checked, `$checkv` will always be the selected check. I figured you must need some sort of priority, though, right? To change the priority of the check boxes just switch up the order in which these conditional statements are carried out.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No $checkv doesn't have to be checked always, its up to the costumer if he wants to have that product in the pack. If he wants just one product he pays the normal price for that product if he wants 2 products he gets a discount and if he wants 3 products he gets even more discount.

Answer (score 0):

If the below is right:

A user checks 2 boxes and receives 1 discount, checks 1 box - no discount, 3 boxed - more discount

then you need to decrement number of the checked boxes:

```
<?php

    if ($_POST['sub']){

        extract($_POST);

        $discount = $checkv + $checkb + $checke - 1;
        $total = $total - $procent * $discount;
    }
?>
```

$procent is 0.1 instead (the value to substract from 1)

So if the 3 boxes are checked the discount will be 0.8 and 0.9 for 2 boxes.

You can also use pow PHP function, so for 2 product the discount is 0.9, 3 - 0.81, 4 - 0.73, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help but notice that you where using 000webhost as your host and as a former user of their services, I must say their PHP and mySQL just doesn't tend to work right. Perhaps try to install XAMPP on your computer for client side editing and displaying. :)